# centering everything in a <section> tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to center everything in the `<section>` tag which is within the `container` class. i tried using this css but it still wont center, it still aligns left. any idea what i'm missing? I also tried adding **!important**, just in case too, but got the same results.

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"].centered, .centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

here is my HTML

```
  <section id="how">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 centered">
                    <h2>How It Works</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2 how-it-works">
                    <h6>1. Schedule your pick-up</h6>
                    <div class="img_box">
                        <img src="images/dirty_square.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        bla bla bla bla bla
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span2 how-it-works">
                    <h6>Step 2: Hand off</h6>
                    <div class="img_box">
                        <img src="images/bag_square.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        bla bla bla bla bla
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span2 how-it-works">
                    <h6>Step 3: Enjoy</h6>
                    <div class="img_box">
                        <img src="images/folded_square.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        bla bla bla bla bla
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-container">
                <a href="/orders.html" class="btn btn-large btn-info">
                click here
              </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WesWz/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set a width to the container div?

```
div.container{
    width:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i want it to center in the container tho

Comment: How about adding another div under the container and set a width?

Comment: still don't work. added a `<div class='centered'>` under the container class